# Exterior Derivative (Constant function)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exterior-derivative

I'm curious if I have a function $f$ and another function $g$. And I have the condition

$$gdf = 0$$

where $df$ is the exterior derivative of $f$ and $g \ne 0$.

Does that imply that it must necessarily be the case that $$f = Constant$$

Comment: Is this on a connected manifold? What's the relevance of $g$ in your question?

Comment: I'm using it in the context of a physics problem, where g represents a function that is not identically 0 everywhere. In the problem I want to show that f is necessarily constant , I have derived that gdf = 0, so I'm just curious if I can conclude right away that f is constant.

Comment: Not identically zero is not what $g\ne 0$ signifies. If $g$ is zero on a large set (one with nonempty interior), then $f$ can do whatever it wants on that set.

Comment: ahh okay thanks. If g is not identically 0 over the set I'm considering or the measure of the set is not 0 over which g is not 0, then can I conclude f is a constant?

Comment: No, the issue is where $g$ *is* zero, as I already said.

Comment: What if g is strictly positive? Then can i conclude f is a constant?

Comment: Wherever $g$ is not zero, you can multiply by $1/g$, right? You still have to know you're on a connected domain.

Comment: ahh yes thanks for all your help. One last question (because I do not know much about exterior derivatives) , for normal scalar functions, do they have the same property as regular derivatives that df = 0, implies f is a constant.

Comment: I've already said this twice. A third time: If your domain is disconnected, $f$ need not be constant.